# How does spyOn and mock works in vitest?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, testing, vite, vitest

I call spyOn on an imported module, but when I run the test, the actual implementation is passed to my testing module.

Here is a link with exact error I'm getting

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitest-dev-vitest-3r9tmb?file=test%2FuseGameStatusStorage.test.ts

```js
//Test file

import * as database from '../../database'
import * as useDateHook from '../useDate'
import * as useStorageHook from '../useStorage'
import { useGameStatusStorage } from '.'

const getStorageMock = vi.fn()
const setStorageMock = vi.fn()
const getTodayMock = vi.fn()
const isSameDateMock = vi.fn()
const getDailyWordMock = vi.fn()

describe('useGameStatusStorage', () => {
  afterEach(() => vi.clearAllMocks())
  vi.spyOn(useStorageHook, 'useStorage').mockReturnValue({
    getStorage: getStorageMock,
    setStorage: setStorageMock,
  })

  vi.spyOn(useDateHook, 'useDate').mockReturnValue({
    getToday: getTodayMock,
    isSameDate: isSameDateMock,
  })

  vi.spyOn(database, 'getDailyWordFromDatabase').mockImplementation(
    getDailyWordMock
  )

  it('Should call getStorage and setStorage with correct params when refreshGame is called', async () => {
    const todayMock = 'TODAY-MOCK'
    const dailyWordMock = 'DAILY-WORD-MOCKs'

    getTodayMock.mockReturnValue(todayMock)
    getDailyWordMock.mockReturnValue(dailyWordMock)

    useGameStatusStorage().refreshGame()

    expect(getStorageMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    expect(setStorageMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    expect(setStorageMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      guesses: [],
      gameFinishStatus: null,
      lastDate: todayMock,
      dailyWord: dailyWordMock,
    })
  })
})

// useGameStatusStorage file

import { getDailyWordFromDatabase } from '../../database'
import { useDate } from '../useDate'
import { useStorage } from '../useStorage'

const { getToday } = useDate()
const today = getToday()
const defaultGuessStatistics: number[] = Array(GUESSES_AMOUNT).fill(0)

const defaultGameStatusStorage: GameStatusStorage = {
  bestStreak: 0,
  guesses: [],
  guessStatistics: defaultGuessStatistics,
  totalGamesAmount: 0,
  winPercentage: 0,
  winStreak: 0,
  gameFinishStatus: null,
  winAmount: 0,
  lossAmount: 0,
  lastDate: today,
  dailyWord: getDailyWordFromDatabase(today),
}

export const useGameStatusStorage: () => UseGameStatusStorageHook = () => {
  const { getStorage, setStorage } = useStorage<GameStatusStorage>( defaultGameStatusStorage)

  const refreshGame = () => {
    const storage = getStorage()
    setStorage({
      ...storage,
      guesses: [],
      gameFinishStatus: null,
      lastDate: today,
      dailyWord: getDailyWordFromDatabase(today),
    })
  }

  return {
    refreshGame,
  }
}
```

The error i'm getting

```
 FAIL  src/hooks/useGameStatusStorage/useGameStatusStorage.test.ts > useGameStatusStorage > Should call getStorage and setStorage with correct params when refreshGame is called
AssertionError: expected "spy" to be called with arguments: [ { guesses: [], …(3) } ]

Received: 

  1st spy call:

  Array [
    Object {
      "dailyWord": "DAILY-WORD-MOCKs",
      "gameFinishStatus": null,
      "guesses": Array [],
-     "lastDate": "TODAY-MOCK",
+     "lastDate": "2023-07-03",
    },
  ]
```

'2023-07-03' is the actual implementation return from useDate().getToday() module, i've used debugger and checked that getToday have been called before spy (I've tried to use vi.mock but it didnt worked as well)